# django migration is not creating all the fields from defined model class into db

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

Hi i am trying to generate migration but all fields are not getting created into the db. Below is my code.

```
from django.db import models

class News(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 100),
    content = models.CharField(max_length= 100),
    description = models.TextField(default= "")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author

    class Meta:
        db_table = "news"


class SportNews(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 100),
    content = models.CharField(max_length = 100),
    description = models.TextField(default = "")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author

    class Meta:
        db_table = "sports_news"
```

Comment: What commands are you using to create the migrations and actually migrating the database? And which columns are being created and which ones are not?

Comment: i am trying 'python manage.py makemigrations', which is creating only description field .

Comment: Now what happens when you run `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: @Linux Maybe you already have other columns in your database. django's `makemigration` only take **edited** fields and generate migrations for them. Did you check your database table?

Comment: @MattCremeens migrate is also taking only description field and putting it into db. not any other field.

Comment: Do these tables already exist in your database?

Comment: @PedramParsian no dude, this is the fresh migration that i am running, so db do not already have these fields in there.

Comment: @MattCremeens Do these tables already exist in your database?  -> No

Comment: Do any messages get printed to the console after running your migration?

Comment: @MattCremeens Do any messages get printed to the console after running your migration? -> after makemigrations command it says Create Model News, Create model SportNews and after migrate command, it says, it migrates News, and default  models like auth ,sessions , admin .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are putting **comma** after defining each field. Remove them and you are good to go!